# a three battery pack of 3.6V/750mAh

Tags: batteries

This is a battery pack for a 1992 cordless phone. The cells shorter and thicker than a AA cell, I have no idea if they are regular cells. The original charger was replaced by someone with a 14V/500mAh one giving out 18V when no charging/ 5V when charging. I have to replace the cells because they are dead. What min/max specs should the voltage have?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a picture please include. From the text it could be a battery pack with 3 or 4 cells. I remember such batteries from the past but more info is needed.

Comment: Please measure the dimensions of the battery. Sounds like SubC, but it’s just a guess without measurements.

Answer (score 0):

If this is from 1992, then this must be NiCad 3S (in-series) battery pack, 3.6 V nominal. As you said, the capacity is 750 mA-h. [Every RadioShack](https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-3-6v-700mah-ni-cd-battery-for-at-t-v-tech) used to sell replacements of this sort,

[image]

There are still places where they can build a replacement pack with right size of cells. The charging voltage for a healthy pack should reach about 1.45 V per cell (~4.35 V total), and the charger should stop either when the cells start overheating, or by monitoring a subtle change in voltage increase, see [BatteryUniversity aticle BU-407](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_based_batteries).

However, it is highly recommended to throw the whole thing away.

Comment: Thanks. How can I attach pics of the cells pack? It seems from your answer that a 5V charger will be sufficient, correct?